# Travel Visa to India for a Week

Tags: visas, air-travel, india, mumbai

I am a US citizen hoping to visit India for a week in October, and according to the Internet there are multiple options to go about for the VISA route, but the online one seems the simplest. However, it costs a decent bit, so I want to make sure I'm doing things right before applying. Do I need to have my plane ticket squared away for sure before I apply? Is it a big deal if I'm not sure the *exact* dates I will be there (I'd only be off by a day or two). Anything else I should be aware of? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since April 2019, the [India e-Tourist and e-Business visas](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html) are now valid for [one year and for multiple entries](https://pib.gov.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid=188642). You need to apply at least four days before your expected date of arrival. You'll need return or onward tickets out of India, but you don't have to buy them before applying for the e-visa. If you aren't sure when you will arrive, you should put down the earliest possible date you think you might arrive.

Comment: Thanks! A little more about my situation: I'm traveling with a family member who's going there on business purposes, but I personally am just there to tourist around (in Mumbai and potentially Bengaluru). Is there anything I should be aware of when completing the VISA form?

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books It's pretty straightforward. You do need to print it out and take a copy with you, and show it to Indian immigration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: "pretty straightforward" is a huge assertion. My tip: write down every code, links you receive. Double check everything. Prepare photo of your passport [in PDF, not too large] and of yourself [in JPG]. Take time to do eVisa, it is a test of your fitness to go to India ;-). It is possibly one of the most confusing visa (and evisa) site.

Comment: Is getting the e-Tourist visa the path I should be taking? Or is there a better/more inexpensive way to get a VISA?

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books The traditional visa is a lot more work to get. The e-visa is (relatively) quick and easy.